# Testing navigation in React component

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router, jestjs

I'd like to test that the url changes, when a submit button is pressed. As part of the test, I'm checking that the initial url is "/auth" and the url becomes "/".

A simpler test is failing, though, with the initial url test.

Test:

```
it("displays an authcode and submit button", async() => {
    history = createMemoryHistory();
    
    const root = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(root);
    render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/auth"]}>
            <App />
        </MemoryRouter>,
        root
    );

    expect(screen.queryByTestId('bad-code-message').classList.contains('hidden')).toBe(true);
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Auth code:')).toBeVisible();
    expect(screen.getByRole('button')).toBeVisible();
    expect(location.pathname).toBe("/auth");
});
```

App component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProtectedRoute } from './ProtectedRoute';
import { CreateProfileWithRouter } from './CreateProfileComponent';
import { ActivityList } from './ActivityListComponent';
import { TokenEntryWithRouter } from './TokenEntryComponent';

export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={ActivityList} />
                <Route path="/login" component={CreateProfileWithRouter} />
                <Route path="/auth" component={TokenEntryWithRouter} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Result:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "/auth"
    Received: "/"
```

Comment: MemoryRouter isn't supposed to affect location.pathname, that's the purpose of it.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error, I figured something out. "/" is the initial url, but I don't know how to change that. I'm passing the url that the component will navigate to and asserting that "/" is the url, at the beginning, and, when navigation is tested, I assert the url has changed to the passed in url.

I'm also using Router instead of MemoryRouter. I had a hunch from the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing) that the history prop, which is passed into the component (with "withRouter"), gets changed in a way that could be tested.

Before all tests:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    createPermanentAuthSpy = jest.spyOn(yasClient, "createPermanentAuth");

    history = createMemoryHistory();
    
    const root = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(root);
    render(
        <Router history={history}>
            <TokenEntryWithRouter navigateToOnAuthentication="/dummy" />
        </Router>,
        root
    );

    token = screen.getByLabelText('Auth code:');
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('bad-code-message').classList.contains('hidden')).toBe(true);
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/");
});
```

Testing navigation:

```
it("navigates to '/', when a good token is entered.", async() => {
    createPermanentAuthSpy.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(true));
    await act(async() => {
        fireEvent.change(token, {  target: { value: '1' } });
        fireEvent.submit(screen.getByTestId('create-permanent-auth'));
    });

    expect(createPermanentAuthSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(token.classList.contains('valid-data')).toBe(true);
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('bad-code-message').classList.contains('hidden')).toBe(true);
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/dummy");
});
```